# Как добавлять изображения в input[type=file]?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Здравствуйте. Сделал форму для добавления изображений и нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе новых изображений не пропадали те которые пользователь уже выбрал.
Возможно это как то можно сделать с использование js например? Только без подключения разных библиотек (кроме jQuery).

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: Возможно есть смысл продемонстрировать ваш код для того что бы ответ на ваш вопрос занял меньше времени.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, добавил код

Comment: Сброс предыдущего выбора - это единственный способ отменить выбор файла.

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726439/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-one-file-input-element

Comment: @1d0, там речь об отправке нескольких файлов, а мне нужно манипулировать ими при выборе

Comment: @Abmin что значит манипулировать? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Я же написал в вопросе, например пользователь выбрал изображение, когда он еще раз выберет изображение в форме, оно заменит предыдущее а не добавит.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File много кода писать для демонстрации, но вам нужен этот интерфейс

Comment: @zb', спасибо вам